# Lumen Nginx assets path issues

Tags: docker, nginx, configuration, lumen

Having the following nginx configuration in docker container for Lumen

Docker compose nginx service

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_SUFFIX}_nginx
    build: docker/nginx
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8099:80"
    #volumes:
    #  - ./app/public:/var/www/html/app/public
```

Docker install

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Lumen Nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html/public;
  index index.php index.htm index.html;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /index.php {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_connect_timeout 10s;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
      fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
  }
}
```

none of the assets files are loaded. I'm getting 404 (`example http://localhost:8099/front/css/app.css`) as response however the path is correct. How can I debug this issue correctly

Comment: What's an example URL that's not getting loaded?  How would that file get into the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I made an update on my issue

Comment: How is that file supposed to get into the container?  (Or does the back-end PHP script return it?)  Nothing is in the image you build unless you `COPY` it in.